# Jquery UI sortable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've been trying to get the sortable function to work, searched a lot of articles but so far no success.

The basics are just get the simple ul to become sortable like the nice example on jqueryui.com
The problem being, i'm doing everything as suggested but it's just ignoring me.

here is what i currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/N63qQ/

html:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="item_1">bla</li>
    <li id="item_2">bla</li>
</ul>
```

js in the onload(and no onload is not in fact the problem)

```
$(function () {
    $('#sortable').droppable({
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drop: function () {
            alert('delete!');
        }
    });
    $('#item').sortable();
});
```

EDIT: ah got it, was using a wrong jquery ui lib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be sortable, not dropable. Here is your code http://jsfiddle.net/N63qQ/4/

```
$(function () {
$('#sortable').sortable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function () {
        alert('delete!');
    }
});
$('#item').sortable();
});
```

You also forgot to include Jquery UI in your code